# YML ERROR IndentationError: expected an indented block in ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am getting the indentationError: expected an indented block when i try to run the ansiple playbook.I have validate in https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/.

The similar yml is working for other servers

### Working

```
 ---

# Getting thename of the .txt file
- name: Getting name for anchor.txt 
  shell: "ls /mule/ansible/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1/*.txt"
  register: the_file

- debug: msg="{{ the_file }}"

- set_fact: app_folder="{{ the_file.stdout | replace('-anchor.txt','') }}"

- debug: msg="{{ app_folder }}"

# Delete the .txt file
- name: Delete the anchor.txt file
  file: path="{{ the_file.stdout }}" state=absent 

# Wait until the app folder disappears
- name: Wait for the folder to 
  wait_for: path="{{ app_folder }}" state=absent

# Copy the zip file
- name: Copy the zip file 
  copy: src="../analytic-mule-services-mule-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip" dest="/mule/ansible/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1"
```

### Not working

```
 ---

# Getting thename of the .txt file
- name: Getting name for anchor.txt file in 
  shell: "ls /app_2/ansible/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1/*.txt"
  register: the_file

- debug: msg="{{ the_file }}"

- set_fact: app_folder="{{ the_file.stdout | replace('-anchor.txt','') }}"

- debug: msg="{{ app_folder }}"

# Delete the .txt file
- name: Delete the anchor.txt file in 
  file: path="{{ the_file.stdout }}" state=absent 

# Wait until the app folder disappears
- name: Wait for the folder to disappear
  wait_for: path="{{ app_folder }}" state=absent

# Copy the zip file
- name: Copy the zip file to 
  copy: src="../analytic-platform-service-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip" dest="/app_2/ansible/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1"
```

Comment: It would help I guess to also enter the "similar" working YAML ;-) sometimes putting this on a single page helps - or maybe best check a diff?

Comment: Updated the script

Comment: It looks unreadable again (every line of code has to be prepended by 4 spaces. Is this now the correct and the failing one? Then which is which? Thanks.

Comment: Verified but no diffrence

Comment: Could please help me where ?

Comment: Updated working and non working yml

Comment: I'll come back to it later - hexdump coud indicate weird characters or did already usw diff on both of them? When I have access to a real keyboard again I'll help you with the code formating. It currently looks like html styled lists not like YAML . Thanks for being responsive.

Comment: Did you check the line break types of each yml. Are they the same? And configure your editor to show tabs and whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** (maybe reporting artefact): The non working has a space (in the question at least) before the initial `---`

A (unified) diff with the leading space in non-working version removed):

```
$ diff -u so_ansible_{not,''}working.yml 
--- so_ansible_notworking.yml   2016-06-02 11:18:09.000000000 +0200
+++ so_ansible_working.yml  2016-06-02 11:16:04.000000000 +0200
@@ -1,8 +1,8 @@
 ---

 # Getting thename of the .txt file
-- name: Getting name for anchor.txt file in 
-  shell: "ls /app_2/ansible/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1/*.txt"
+- name: Getting name for anchor.txt 
+  shell: "ls /mule/ansible/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1/*.txt"
   register: the_file

 - debug: msg="{{ the_file }}"
@@ -12,13 +12,13 @@
 - debug: msg="{{ app_folder }}"

 # Delete the .txt file
-- name: Delete the anchor.txt file in 
+- name: Delete the anchor.txt file
   file: path="{{ the_file.stdout }}" state=absent 

 # Wait until the app folder disappears
-- name: Wait for the folder to disappear
+- name: Wait for the folder to 
   wait_for: path="{{ app_folder }}" state=absent

 # Copy the zip file
-- name: Copy the zip file to 
-  copy: src="../analytic-platform-service-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip" dest="/app_2/ansible/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1"
\ No newline at end of file
+- name: Copy the zip file 
+  copy: src="../analytic-mule-services-mule-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip" dest="/mule/ansible/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1"
\ No newline at end of file
```

So if there are no alien characters inside (`\r` or tabs mixed with spaces that might have gotten lost in copy, paste and submit to server at SO) then the only thing I noticed is the Hint above. Please use either an editor as suggested by @bent-blue or hexdump/xxd/whatnot which I suggested in my comment, to ensure the scripts receive what you intend.

**Update from OP**:
I have modified even I got same error.
I walthrough line by line, but neither ("unexpected sorts of" white space nor tabs)

```
---
# Getting thename of the .txt file
- name: Getting name for anchor.txt file in host apsrd3277 and apsrd4450
  shell: "ls /mule/ansible/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1/*.txt"
  register: the_file
- debug: msg="{{ the_file }}"
- set_fact: app_folder="{{ the_file.stdout|replace('-anchor.txt','') }}"
- debug: msg="{{ app_folder }}"
# Delete the .txt file
- name: Delete the anchor.txt file in apsrd3277 and apsrd4450
  file: path="{{ the_file.stdout }}" state=absent
# Wait until the app folder disappears
- name: Wait for the folder to disappear in apsrd3277 and apsrd4450
  wait_for: path = "{{ app_folder }}" state=absent
# Copy the zip file
- name: Copy the zip file to apsrd3277 and apsrd4450
  copy: src="../analytic-core-services-mule-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip" dest="/mule/ansible/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.1"
```

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand how to do that from my side. The (non) working `.yml` files are unmodified on your computer only and thus it would be most helpful, if you can analyze these with eg. hexdump/xxd or find differences via diff or as bent-blue suggested in an editor that shows "dangerous" characters explicitely (like tabs and line ending characters different from your platform convention. HTH.

Comment: Added latest yml.got same issue

Comment: So it was not the broken indent of the first `---` and you have no weird characters different from the on to the other. Is there any python source that is executed in the process of "playing the book" that might be different and thus also throw a bad indent execption or so: Maybe it helps to have the verbatim copy of the error in the question?

Comment: {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
  File "/home/anlytcd/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1464862687.17-200174242158236/setup", line 107
    
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2